# Is there any extension for VS copying code position?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to copy code position with namespace, function name, class name, line number etc.
I will paste this values to team project for task/bug entry.

Comment: Could you please explain it more in detail? Or possibly give an example of what you are trying to acheive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio code model and [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to copy exactly what you need. For example, the following command copies file, line and namespace.class.function:

```
EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
if (ts == null)
  return;
EnvDTE.CodeFunction func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction]
            as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
if (func == null)
  return;

string result = DTE.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName + System.Environment.NewLine +
  "Line " + ts.CurrentLine + System.Environment.NewLine +
  func.FullName;
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(result);
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\sv\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs
Line 12
ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main
```