# Get line number and filename in a few clicks

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

Usually I need to send my colleagues some explanation or "address" of some feature in code. I do it by getting full path of file and typing number of line — 2 clicks + remembering and typing number + removing the begin of path (disk name and unnecessary folders).
Is it so rarely need?
Especially it's strange because Resharper has opportunity to navigate to line number, but there is no way to grab this info fastly.

Is there any way to get "code address" in a few clicks?

Comment: Are they asking for the line number in the source code, or an address, such as a thrown exception might provide? You seem to think the former, but the latter is more probable. They could easily find the line number if you told them the name of the method in question.

Comment: Usually it's about line of source code. I understand that it's trivial problem, but mostly we communicate in writing, and it takes some time to show them where some process is started, for example.

Comment: If you are all working on the same version of the code (that is to say, you're using a source code management system), giving a line number will work. Otherwise, your line numbers may not match up. Assuming you *are* using something like Git, it might be easiest just to tell them the name of the file and method in question (such as "The code is in bla.cs, in the Platypus() method").

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502847/is-there-any-extension-for-vs-copying-code-position