# Visual studio extension to copy file path and line number

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm looking for extension or native hotkey to copy full file path and line number and column under caret or current method name and current line. What I intend to do is

1. place caret in particular place in my code
2. press hotkey
3. share with my colleague something like that: 
   `s:\projects\work\myProject\models\mymodel.cs: method PrintString(string text), line 50`

Comment: Pair programming works best when you are sitting next to the person, close enough to see this for yourself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502847/is-there-any-extension-for-vs-copying-code-position