# How to copy the Visual studio current line number

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

How to copy/get the current line number in the active document of Visual Studio using C#

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502847/is-there-any-extension-for-vs-copying-code-position

Comment: @Sergey Vlasov: Oh, sorry, I didn't know that this question was answered - I had searched but couldn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to add references "envDTE" and "envDTE80" for your C# project.

Then use the following code (I put it into click button event in my case) to copy the line number (and the file name) into clipboard.

```
    private void btnGetLineVS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
        dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
        dte2.MainWindow.Activate();
        int line = ((EnvDTE.TextSelection)dte2.ActiveDocument.Selection).ActivePoint.Line;

        //Show it to the user the way you like
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(dte2.ActiveDocument.FullName);//The file name
        builder.Append('\t');
        builder.Append(line);//The current line
        if (builder.Length > 0)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(builder.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Copied to clipboard");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing!");
    }
```

Thanks to Reder's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724025/4608491) that I know this kind of thing exist, I always thought to do this, we have to use VSIX Visual Studio code project.