# Getting method name in Visual Studio 2017 extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I want to build a Visual Studio 2017 extension that will help me automate a task. It will be available in the context menu (right click menu) of the code pane.

For that I need to recognize the method the cursor is pointing to, it's class, namespace and parameters. The documentation for doing that seems scarce.

Can anyone help me get in the right path to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502847/is-there-any-extension-for-vs-copying-code-position

Comment: Agree with Sergey Vlasov, do your resolve the issue by using Sergey Vlasov's code sample? if yes, please post a reply and mark it as answer, if not, please provide a bit more information.