# Visual Studio IDE: copy location for reference

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Many a time I need to reference a location in my code, e.g. send it to another developer.

For example, I'd like to locate the cursor somewhere in my code, right-click --> Copy location, and then paste would give me:

```
File: [file path & name]
Function: [Function/method name]
Line: [line number and contents of line]
```

Is there a tool or a plugin that does it for Visual Studio?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502847/is-there-any-extension-for-vs-copying-code-position

Comment: Simply great, I love your website! Comment accepted as an answer - how do I do it?

Comment: When referring to another answer, there is no need to accept it separately.